# How to place Content DIV on bootstrap carousel and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a content `DIV` on bootstrap carousel in large and desktop screens. See below image for your understanding.

[image: Example on screen]

In mobile and tab screen it should be something like this -

[image: Example on mobile]

I am not sure how to create this layout using bootstrap 3. Hope somebody may help me out.

This is my current Mark Up:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main">

  <div id="homepage-feature" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#homepage-feature" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#homepage-feature" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active" style="background: url(img/slider/uniform.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Providing you the Best</h3>
            <h1>Cleaning Companies</h1>
            <p>in Bahrain with 10% Discount.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" style="background: url(img/slider/uniform.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.carousel-inner -->

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#homepage-feature" data-slide="prev">
                &lsaquo;
            </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#homepage-feature" data-slide="next">
                &rsaquo;
            </a>
  </div>
  <!-- /#homepage-feature.carousel -->

  <div style="width: 300px; height: 500px; background: red;"></div>

</main>
```

Comment: Use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to detect the browser window size and style the content div accordingly.

Comment: @anpsmn, Yes I can use media queries. But problem is how to place content DIV on carousel in desktop and large screen sizes..

Comment: Check my fiddle below. I used queries to achieve this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

## DEMO: https://jsbin.com/lufoli

Mirror the size of the .container at every break width and that is the parent called "`.red`". Center that `.red` absolute positioned element by using left: 50% and then a negative margin 1/2 the width at every break point. Then add the form/div inside that parent and flush it right at the min-width.

**CSS**

```
.slide-wrapper {
    position: relative
}

.red {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.red-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .carousel-caption {
        text-align: left;
        padding-right: 300px;
    }
    .red {
        width: 750px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 20px 0;
        margin-left: -375px;
    }
    .red-content {
        width: 300px;
        float: right;
        height: 100%;
        background: red;
        color: #fff;
        margin-right:15px; /* width of .container gutter */
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .red {
        width: 970px;
        margin-left: -485px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    .red {
        width: 1170px;
        margin-left: -585px;
    }
}

/* MISC */
#homepage-feature .item {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
}
#homepage-feature > .carousel-control {
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
    filter: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
#homepage-feature > .carousel-control span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide-wrapper">
    
   <div id="homepage-feature" class="carousel slide">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#homepage-feature" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li data-target="#homepage-feature" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
     
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          
         <div class="item active" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract)">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
               <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
               <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
               <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
             
         <div class="item" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/1500x600)">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
               <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>
               <p>With "mobile-first" there is now only one percentage-based grid.</p>
               <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
             
      </div>
      <!-- /.carousel-inner -->
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#homepage-feature" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#homepage-feature" data-slide="next">
        <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
      </a>
   </div>
   <!-- /#homepage-feature.carousel -->
   <div class="red">
     
     <div class="red-content">
        Content goes here.
       
     </div>
     
     
   </div>
          
</div>
<!-- /.container.slide-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding row after container, column style as per you requirement. i have made a generic carousel with a block content which can be place anywhere in the carousel and its fully responsive. please have a look to the demo .

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Carousel Styles */
.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #2980b9;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 460px
}

.carousel-control {
    width: 0;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
 opacity: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 background-image: none;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-control.left span {
 padding: 15px;
}

.carousel-control.right span {
 padding: 15px;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, 
.carousel-control .icon-prev, 
.carousel-control .icon-next {
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 z-index: 5;
 display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .icon-prev {
 left: 0;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
 right: 0;
}

.carousel-control.left span,
.carousel-control.right span {
 background-color: #000;
}

.carousel-control.left span:hover,
.carousel-control.right span:hover {
 opacity: .7;
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

/* Carousel Header Styles */
.header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 1.8%;
    right: auto;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #fff;
}

.header-text h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.header-text h2 span {
    background-color: #2980b9;
 
}

.header-text h3 span {
 background-color: #000;
 
}

.btn-min-block {
    min-width: 170px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.btn-theme {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-theme:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <!-- Carousel -->
     <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
       <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
       <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>
   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="First slide">
                    <!-- Static Header -->
                    <div class="header-text ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <h2>
                             <span>Welcome to <strong>demo center</strong></span>
                            </h2>
                            <br>
                            <h3>
                             <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                            </h3>
                            <br>
                            </div>
                    </div><!-- /header-text -->
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <!-- Static Header -->
                    <div class="header-text ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <h2>
                                <span>Welcome to the world of bootstrap</span>
                            </h2>
                            <br>
                            <h3>
                             <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                            </h3>
                            <br>
                             </div>
                    </div><!-- /header-text -->
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <!-- Static Header -->
                    <div class="header-text ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <h2>
                                <span>Bootstrap is awesome</span>
                            </h2>
                            <br>
                            <h3>
                             <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                            </h3>
                            <br>
                             </div>
                    </div><!-- /header-text -->
       </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
   </a>
  </div><!-- /carousel -->
 </div>
</div>
  </body>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: No this is not the way I need. My content DIV should not be working like carousel caption.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/3nsk24my/3/

```
#layer    {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width: 100%;
    z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: No  I can't use `fixed` position in this case

Comment: When  we use `postion:fixed;` its positioning the contents top of the browser window.. But I want to get this content div to above the carousel..

Answer (score 0):

You can position the content div for larger devices and for smaller device remove the absolute position using media queries

```
.green {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
    position:absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) { 
    .green {
        position: relative
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzdUa/126/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when positioning `DIV` on carousel it goes to the right edge of the screen. So I would like to get it to a bootstrap container then position to right edge of the that container. Is it possible?

Comment: You can add that content div inside the carousel wrapper

Comment: Am not sure if I am getting what the issue is. I have set the right to 5px in my fiddle. You can alter that as you want and it would always be inside the parent div.

Comment: space between bootstrap container right edge and screen right edge is differ according to the screen size of the monitor. So I cann't use PX for `right`.

Comment: I tried to fake a gap by giving a width to banner-content and it looks fine even when i resize it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzdUa/132/)

Comment: I tried it with your solution provided by last comment.. But still I could not figure this out correctly.

Comment: What is the exact issue in the fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71850/discussion-between-user3733831-and-anpsmn).

Comment: hello can we chat regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding row, column style within carousel like following, but tweak image resizing css to get the size of div that holds the image and not the original image style defined in bootstrap for carousel image

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
                    <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1500X600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>
                    <p>With "mobile-first" there is now only one percentage-based grid.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v7o4y5af/3/)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this?

Comment: Lepanto, Actually I need to place a different contents above carousel, not carousel caption.

Comment: So it will not slide along the carousel?

Comment: no.. It is not slide along. Its a different content DIV, which I need to position above the carousel in desktop and large screen. In mobile and tab viewports I need to place this content DIV below the carousel.

Comment: anpsmn, solution is not match with my requirement. Because when it position on carouse, it should be position inside a bootstrap container to keep my contents' width properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this valid solution?

I wrapped carousel with `div` and put content div (the green one) inside this div. Then I put some styling:

```
.content-div {
    text-align: center;
    background: #090;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .content-div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/qfawphpe/