# text button is not responding to CSS styling

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to make a website and I am trying to make the header image of the website responsive using media queries. I like the way it looks on desktop, laptop, and tablet viewports but on mobile, however, I am not able to get the text and button to fit well like it does in the other viewports. I want the text and button to be centered on the screen just like in the desktop viewport, but when I try to change the font size of the h1 and h4 tag nothing happens in the mobile media query. I also tried to apply `display: none;` to the h1 element so that it would only be the h4 element and the button on the screen on mobile viewports but when I tried adding `display: none;` nothing happened.

### This is what it looks like on desktop

[image]

### This is what it looks like on mobile

[image]

```css
:root {
    --desktop-min: 1200px;
    --laptop-min: 900px;
    --laptop-max: calc(var(--desktop-min) - 1px);
    --tablet-min: 720px;
    --tablet-max: calc(var(--laptop-min) - 1px);
    --mobile-min: 300px;
    --mobile-max: calc(var(--tablet-min) - 1px);
    }

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}



.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    bottom: auto
    
}

.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 500%;
    transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 15px hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    
}

.carousel-caption h4 {
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    /* margin-top: -1.25rem; */
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    
}

/* .btn-primary {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border-color: 1px solid hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border-color: 1px solid hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
} */


#button {
    background-color:hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#button:hover {
    background-color:hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: var(--laptop-min)) and (max-width: var(--laptop-max)) {
    
    
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 50%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        font-size: 140%;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding-bottom: .2rem;
        margin-top: -1.25rem;       
    }
    #button {
        font-size: 95%;
        padding: 8px 14px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: var(--tablet-min)) and (max-width: var(--tablet-max)) {
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 50%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 350%;
        padding-top: 10px;
        
        
        
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        padding-bottom: .1rem;
        /* margin-top: -1.25rem; */
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 95%;
        padding: 8px 14px;
        
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: var(--mobile-min)) and (max-width: var(--mobile-max)) {
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 40%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 50% !important;
        padding-top: 5px;
        
        
        
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        font-size: 10%;
        /* margin-top: -1.25rem; */
        
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 90%;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        
    }

    .carousel-indicators {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test17.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css"> -->
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="servicesDropdown">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-capitalize text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Contact</a></li>

        <script>
          // Get the Services dropdown link element
          const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
        
          // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
          servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
          });
        
          // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
          if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
            // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
            });
        
            // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
            });
          }
        </script>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

       
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

    <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
    <section>
      <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
        
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption ">
            
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <h4 class=" text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</h4>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 " 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            
            </div>
          
        
        </div> 
      <!-- class="bg-dark text-white text-center text-sm-start p-5 p-lg-0" -->
      <!-- <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div>
            <h1><span class="text-primary"> Solutions</span></h1>
            <p class="lead py-4">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam
              voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos
              exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
              voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos
              exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem.
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote</button>
        </div>
        <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" alt="" class="img-fluid d-none d-lg block"/>
      </div> -->
    </section>
    <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Bootstrap docs for the carousel component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/)do not really mention the usage of HTML content inside of the carousel, but [it can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722010/how-to-place-content-div-on-bootstrap-carousel-and-make-it-responsive)

Inside the carousel, the `.carousel-inner` element has a `overflow: hidden` property on it.  This is how it works from Bootstrap. You will have to manually size things with a media query to prevent them from being cut off.

So my question is: why are you using a carousel here at all?  You only appear to have a single item in your carousel.  If you don't use a carousel here it will be much simpler and have much less code

Comment: The reason why I am using a carousel is because I am trying to create a carousel slider. The code I have in my question is just one slide from the original carousel. I am trying to make this one slide responsive so I can implement the code on all slides of the carousel.

Comment: See the question I linked to: "[How to place Content DIV on bootstrap carousel and make it responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722010/how-to-place-content-div-on-bootstrap-carousel-and-make-it-responsive)"

Comment: thank you so much I found an answer similar to what I need. but I don't much CSS can I please show you what I currently have I'm trying to make it look like the header in my question but with the responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you out!

```css
  :root {
    --desktop-min: 1200px;
    --laptop-min: 900px;
    --laptop-max: calc(var(--desktop-min) - 1px);
    --tablet-min: 720px;
    --tablet-max: calc(var(--laptop-min) - 1px);
    --mobile-min: 300px;
    --mobile-max: calc(var(--tablet-min) - 1px);
    }

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}



.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    bottom: auto
    
}

.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 500%;
    transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 15px hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    
}

.carousel-caption h4 {
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    /* margin-top: -1.25rem; */
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    
}

/* .btn-primary {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border-color: 1px solid hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border-color: 1px solid hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
} */


#button {
    background-color:hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#button:hover {
    background-color:hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: var(--laptop-min)) and (max-width: var(--laptop-max)) {
    
    
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 50%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        font-size: 140%;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding-bottom: .2rem;
        margin-top: -1.25rem;       
    }
    #button {
        font-size: 95%;
        padding: 8px 14px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 50%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        
        
        
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        padding-bottom: .1rem;
        /* margin-top: -1.25rem; */
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 8px 14px;
        
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 40%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px !important;
        padding-top: 5px;
        
        
        
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        font-size: 20px;
        /* margin-top: -1.25rem; */
        
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 90%;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        
    }

    .carousel-indicators {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 30%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 20px !important;
        padding-top: 5px;
        
        
        
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        font-size: 17px;
        /* margin-top: -1.25rem; */
        
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 17px!important;
        /*padding: 4px 8px;*/
        
    }

    .carousel-indicators {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Home | </title>

<!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test17.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css"> -->
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/Bootstrap-T/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="servicesDropdown">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-capitalize text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-e/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Contact</a></li>

        <script>
          // Get the Services dropdown link element
          const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
        
          // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
          servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
          });
        
          // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
          if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
            // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
            });
        
            // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
            });
          }
        </script>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

       
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

    <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
    <section>
      <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
        
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
          <img src="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.livemint.com%2Flm-img%2Fimg%2F2023%2F07%2F10%2F1600x900%2F3-0-58230984-2BJP1XN-0_1679807674932_1689004151190.jpg&tbnid=Cr-XrZfWkquZbM&vet=12ahUKEwiv2aqwwuaAAxXbmicCHaJMB1gQMygBegQIARBu..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.livemint.com%2Fopinion%2Fonline-views%2Fcyber-threats-are-worsening-in-today-s-digital-dystopia-11689003952132.html&docid=Ps2YYy-dnE4UfM&w=1600&h=900&q=cyber&client=firefox-b-d&ved=2ahUKEwiv2aqwwuaAAxXbmicCHaJMB1gQMygBegQIARBu" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption ">

            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <h4 class=" text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</h4>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 " 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            
            </div>
          
        
        </div> 
      <!-- class="bg-dark text-white text-center text-sm-start p-5 p-lg-0" -->
      <!-- <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div>
            <h1><span class="text-primary"></span></h1>
            <p class="lead py-4">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam
              voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos
              exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
              voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos
              exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem.
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote</button>
        </div>
        <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" alt="  logo" class="img-fluid d-none d-lg block"/>
      </div> -->
    </section>
    <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->


  </body>
</html>
```

you should have used the brake points, the header elements, and the button text with pixels.
here are some brake points:
300px,
600px,
768px,
992px,
1200px,
1510px,
1600px.

Comment: test it in your project and see if it works.

Comment: i saw the bootstrap document was giving an !important width to your h1,h4, and button tags. so i gave an Important width to those elements in @media.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I am looking for its just that when the viewport width gets around 300px the h1 elements gets too close to the navbar. Is there a way I can add margin without breaking the responsiveness or is there a way I can make the h1 element disappear when the viewport gets to 300?

Comment: I think that if there is a way to make the h1 tag disappear at a certain viewport that would be my best option

Comment: yes there is a way, you can add another @media query with min 300 & max 400 or 450. then you can change the size or even make h1 disappear using visibility or display in CSS. you can even use the min600 brake point.