# Creating a responsive Bootstrap 5 carousel

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am new to CSS and I am trying to build a responsive bootstrap 5 carousel slider that has a caption and a button. I found a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722010/how-to-place-content-div-on-bootstrap-carousel-and-make-it-responsive) that gave me an answer that is similar to the problem I had originally. I am just trying to figure out how to make the carousel in the answer more like my original carousel. I want the carousel in the answer to be as wide as the original, have the height of the original, and have the text and button centered on the image like the original while keeping the same responsiveness as the answer I found but I don't know how to do that without messing up the responsiveness.

### The Original

```css
@import "./.fonts.css";
:root {
  --desktop-min: 1200px;
    --laptop-min: 900px;
    --laptop-max: calc(var(--desktop-min) - 1px);
    --tablet-min: 720px;
    --tablet-max: calc(var(--laptop-min) - 1px);
    --mobile-min: 300px;
    --mobile-max: calc(var(--tablet-min) - 1px);
}


.c-item {
    height: 90%;
}

.c-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}



#sub-header {
    color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

#button {
    background-color:hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#nav_object {
    position: relative;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}

#nav_object {
    position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    #nav_object::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    #nav_object:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}



@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
/* NEW */

footer p {
  padding-top: 8px !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  footer h4 {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>




<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css"> -->
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="nav_object">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-capitalize text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Contact</a></li>

        
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

    <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
    <section>
      <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="6" aria-label="Slide 7"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="7" aria-label="Slide 8"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="submit-ticket_01"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize"> Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="submit-ticket_01"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="submit-ticket_01"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="submit-ticket_01"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="submit-ticket_01"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="submit-ticket_01"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="submit-ticket_01"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
            <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</p>
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5" 
              id="submit-ticket_01"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
        </div> 
  
    </section>
    <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->

  </body>
</html>
```

### The Current Answer

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Carousel Styles */
.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #2980b9;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 460px
}

.carousel-control {
    width: 0;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-control.left span {
    padding: 15px;
}

.carousel-control.right span {
    padding: 15px;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, 
.carousel-control .icon-prev, 
.carousel-control .icon-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .icon-prev {
    left: 0;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
    right: 0;
}

.carousel-control.left span,
.carousel-control.right span {
    background-color: #000;
}

.carousel-control.left span:hover,
.carousel-control.right span:hover {
    opacity: .7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

/* Carousel Header Styles */
.header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 1.8%;
    right: auto;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #fff;
}

.header-text h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.header-text h2 span {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    
}

.header-text h3 span {
    background-color: #000;
    
}

.btn-min-block {
    min-width: 170px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.btn-theme {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-theme:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Carousel -->
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="First slide">
                    <!-- Static Header -->
                    <div class="header-text ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <h2>
                                <span>Welcome to <strong>demo center</strong></span>
                            </h2>
                            <br>
                            <h3>
                                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                            </h3>
                            <br>
                            </div>
                    </div><!-- /header-text -->
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    <!-- Static Header -->
                    <div class="header-text ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <h2>
                                <span>Welcome to the world of bootstrap</span>
                            </h2>
                            <br>
                            <h3>
                                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                            </h3>
                            <br>
                             </div>
                    </div><!-- /header-text -->
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                    <!-- Static Header -->
                    <div class="header-text ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <h2>
                                <span>Bootstrap is awesome</span>
                            </h2>
                            <br>
                            <h3>
                                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                            </h3>
                            <br>
                             </div>
                    </div><!-- /header-text -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div><!-- /carousel -->
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
```